# Difference Between "if_ether.h" and "ether.h"

Tags: networking, tcp

I am currently trying to build an easy TCP  structure in C, following the OSI model,

And I just found that there are 2 differents type of "ether" use no kernel related, which are using similar struct,
I guess the "if_ether.h" intervene if a L2 layer does not exist ?
Or an address is not set.

While the "ether.h" is there to configure directly if a use of the L2 is done.

Or is it something who intervene in case of protocol like "PPP", or anything who may bypass the L2 like a Rawsocket

Some stuff are blur.
Thank you in advance to share your light with me.

Take care !

Comment: Header files are not layers. Header files don't do things.

Comment: these are used to configured existing layer ?

Comment: functions do things. Header files just tell the compiler lists of functions you can call and structs you can use.

Comment: [tag:osi] is not relevant here.